# Android navigation bar on left side

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

There is a task to display the navigation bar on the left side for android 4.4.2. Nothing of the sort found. Is it possible to do this? 
Or, for example, to hide the navigation bar, and on the left side add own custom menu on the same level of layouts hierarchy order content is shifted to the size of the menu?
This solution should work everywhere, not just in one application. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is a uinavigationbar?

Comment: by uinavigationbar i mean this http://take.ms/TO20f

Comment: That is referred to as the "navigation bar".

Comment: You mean like a navigation drawer?

Comment: No. I need this panel on the left side 
http://take.ms/A4n8w

Comment: That is the soft navigation keys. If you do not have hard keys on a device such as the Nexus 5, Android will provide you with them.

Comment: @zgc7009 There are significant differences between the Navigation Drawer (and the Action Bar for that matter,) and the standard navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you see that navigation bar there because you are using emulator genymotion. On real devices you should not be able to see it. Besides, those back button are physical buttons on some devices like samsung s2.

If you want a menu on the left you should implement navigation drawer. Good luck

Comment: by Jared Burrows from the comments to the question: 
That is the soft navigation keys. If you do not have hard keys on a device such as the Nexus 5, Android will provide you with them